# Calling mysql_query() on another database, assumes WordPress using that database

Tags: mysql, terms

I'm attempting to import some data from a legacy site into WordPress. First step is terms for taxonomy `event_category`. Here is my approach:

```
$link = mysql_connect(
    'localhost',
    'blah',
    'blah'
);

// connect to old database
$dkpl_db = mysql_select_db('dkpldump', $link);

$event_categories = mysql_query('SELECT * FROM calendar_cats');
while($event_category = mysql_fetch_assoc($event_categories)){
    //create term!
    $term = wp_insert_term(
        $event_category['categoryId'],
        'event_category',
        array(
            'slug' => $event_category['categoryName']
        )
    );
    var_dump($term);
}
```

In my `var_dump` I'm getting following error:

```
WP_Error Object
(
    [errors] => Array
    (
        [db_insert_error] => Array
        (
            [0] => Could not insert term into the database
        )
    )
    [error_data] => Array
    (
        [db_insert_error] => Table 'dkpldump.wp_terms' doesn\'t exist
    )
)
```

The problem is `dkpldump` is the database I'm trying to *read* from, not the database WordPress is installed on (`dkpl`). So why is it trying to write to `dkpldump` database and how can I fix it?

Comment: What happens if you pass $link as the second parameter of mysql_query?  Would recommend using mysqli too, even if this is just a one time thing.

Comment: Same thing happens if I pass `$link` to `mysql_query`, going to try `MYSQLi` now if I can

Comment: Works splendidly with `mysqli`, and I was forced to _improve_ to a better mysql class. Thanks @AndrewBartel

Comment: @AndrewBartel if you want to submit such an answer formally, I'll gladly accept it

Comment: Hey Ghost @Parham's answer is actually the best practices way to do it.  Thanks though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a new instance of `wpdb` to connect and read from the other database:

```
$mydb = new wpdb('blah','blah','dkpldump','localhost');
$event_categories = $mydb->get_results("SELECT * FROM calendar_cats");
foreach( $event_categories as $event_category ){
    //create term!
    $term = wp_insert_term(
        $event_category->categoryId,
        'event_category',
        array(
            'slug' => $event_category->categoryName
        )
    );
}
```